# error when sort fields in gridview

Tags: c#

I had Grid view and I added property allow sorting in it and I converted all fields in grid view to item template and after that this error appeared (The GridView 'GridView1' fired event sorting which wasn't handled)
Please anyone help me
.

'>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                '>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                '>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not binding your GridView to SqlDataSource and you are setting its AllowSorting to true, you need to do sorting manually. You need to assign sorting event to the GridView, and write your own code to implement the sorting. You can refer to the code below, and modify accordingly.

**On aspx page:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting">
</asp:GridView>
```

**On codebehind:**

```
public partial class GridViewSort : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
    private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";

    public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

            return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
        }
        set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
            return;

        GridView1.DataSource = GetStaff();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

        if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
        }   
    }

    private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
    {
        DataTable dt = GetStaff();

        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dummy data
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private DataTable GetStaff()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(i, "Staff - " + i, 20 );
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```